# Although the build-tools 28.0.3 in sdk maneger has been downloaded, but still i can only add library dependency 27.1.1 in gradle. what i do?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, platform

Given that I downloaded build-tools version 28.0.3 using sdk-maneger , still only show the version 27.1.1 when I want to add a library in the gradle.

compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 28.

what i do to use build tools 28 in my gradle ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to also update your graddle plugin. Clean and rebuild project and see what happens. Also I strongly recommend using androidX